# Calculate latency for touch screen UI running on ARM controller board running Linux

Tags: linux, touch, linux-device-driver

I have an embedded board which has ARM controller, runs Linux as OS, which also has touch based screen. The data to the screen is taken from the Frame Buffer (/dev/fb0). Is there any way we can calculate the response time between two UI screen switching occurs when any option is selected by touch?

Comment: The phrase "*touch response time between two UI screen switching occurs*" is a little confusing. Can you please clarify exactly what you want to profile...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 latencies involved in the above scenario

#### 1. Time taken for the touchscreen to register the finger and raise an input-event.

- Usually a few milliseconds.
- Enable [FTRACE](http://lwn.net/Articles/365835/) and log the following with timestamps
  -- ISR
  -- Entry of Bottom-half
  -- Invoking of `input_report()`

#### 2. Time taken by the app responsible for the GUI to update it.

- Depending upon the app/framework, usually the most significant contributor to latency.
- Add normal console logs with timestamps in the GUI app's code
  -- upon receiving the input event
  -- just before the command to modify the GUI

#### 3. The time taken by the display to update.

- Usually within 15-30 milliseconds

The final latency is a sum-total of the above 3 latencies.